# Index error: index 14285 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 14285

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a dataframe to a csv file.
when I run this command `df.to_csv("somefile.csv")`.
I am getting below error:

> IndexError: index 14285 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 14285

I checked length of index and data, both are same.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(preds,columns = ['PA','PB','PC','PD','PE','PF','PG'], index =[X_valid_full['ID']])

len(preds)

len(X_valid_full['ID'].unique())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-4113bef3e95d> in <module>
----> 1 df.to_csv("somefile.csv")

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3018                                  doublequote=doublequote,
   3019                                  escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 3020         formatter.save()
   3021 
   3022         if path_or_buf is None:

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in save(self)
    170                 self.writer = UnicodeWriter(f, **writer_kwargs)
    171 
--> 172             self._save()
    173 
    174         finally:

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in _save(self)
    286                 break
    287 
--> 288             self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
    289 
    290     def _save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i):

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in _save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i)
    313 
    314         libwriters.write_csv_rows(self.data, ix, self.nlevels,
--> 315                                   self.cols, self.writer)

pandas\_libs\writers.pyx in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows()

IndexError: index 14285 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 14285
```

Comment: can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Can you give a full example? What is `preds`?

Comment: Can you try to create/save the dataframe without setting the index? And also maybe to save a part of it, with `df.head(n)` - with n = 10, 100, 1000, 10000 etc? Isolating whether it's a specific row it happens on, maybe.

Comment: If I save without setting the index it is working fine.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(preds[:14285],columns = ['PA','PB','PC','PD','PE','PF','PG'],index = [X_valid_full['ID'][:14285]])  this works fine. If I change the value to 14286, it throws the same error.

```df.iloc[14285]
PA    22.22
PB    16.40
PC    13.24
PD    10.84
PE     8.93
PF     7.74
PG     6.66
Name: (PR54286,), dtype: float64 ```

I can not find anything different with values at this index

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be passing the dataframe constructor argument, index, a list with a series instead of just the raw index. This has the effect

In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame(preds,columns = ['PA','PB','PC','PD','PE','PF','PG','PH','PI','PJ'], index = [X_valid_full['ID']])

In [23]: df
Out[23]:

```
    PA  PB  PC  PD  PE  PF  PG  PH  PI  PJ
ID
0    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
2   20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
3   30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
4   40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
5   50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
6   60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
7   70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
8   80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
9   90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```

But I am still able to get to_csv to write the csv file. What I think may be happening is that there are duplicate id's in your 'ID' column.

Because you are using unique in len(X_valid_full['ID'].unique()), you are getting the same size as preds.

A way to address this may be to use X_valid_full.set_index('ID',inplace=True) either before calling the DataFrame constructor or in the constructor without inplace=True. You can also use X_valid_full['ID'].unique() as your index as it appears to be the same size as your preds 1st dimension.

Comment: I checked for duplicates. No duplicate values are there in 'ID'.
The output len(X_valid_full['ID'].unique()) is same as the output of len(X_valid_full['ID']).
I tried all what you have suggested but still getting the same error.